# Draw something under highstock chart navigator

Tags: highcharts

In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QWKUe/232/) you see that the circle I'am trying to draw doesn't show up correctly, it's not possible to draw anything under the navigator of highstock.

what should I do so I can draw under the navigator ?

```
renderer.circle(100, 180, 50).attr({
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1,
    zIndex: 3
}).add();
```

Comment: Interesting. When I set the `zIndex` to 0 it is underneath the navigator series but not underneath the navigator scroll panel or border elements.

Comment: Nice catch-up, but I'm not trying to draw on the navigator, I just want the circle or anything I draw there to show up completely. maybe my question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question now it is that you want to add some drawn elements below the navigator location (not behind). To do this you would need to play with your chart's size (which you are handling in your `div` it looks like) and then by adding the following:

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    spacingBottom: 150
},
```

The [`spacingBottom`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingBottom) (and the other `spacing*`) options let you format the non-chart chart area spaces.

I did some changes to your jsFiddle to demo one way to accomplish this [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ekys4/).